# What is the docker run -r flag

Tags: docker, docker-run, gitleaks

I am looking at this repo:
https://github.com/zricethezav/gitleaks

To run with Docker we'd use

```
docker run --rm --name=gitleaks zricethezav/gitleaks -v -r https://github.com/zricethezav/gitleaks.git
```

I am having trouble figuring out what the `-r` flag is doing...it doesn't look like it's making it read-only, does anyone know?

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-v -r ...` apply to the container process **not** to the `docker` command.

The way to read this is in 2 parts:

1. Run a command `gitleaks` using `docker run --rm --name=gitleaks zricethezav/gitleaks`
2. Provide `gitleaks` flags and params with `-v -r https://github.com/zricethezav/gitleaks.git`

You can (often) determine what flags|parameters a container instance wants by running the process without any flags|parameters or giving it `--help`, i.e.

```sh
docker run -it --name=gitleaks zricethezav/gitleaks --help
Usage:
  gitleaks [OPTIONS]

Application Options:
  -r, --repo=          Repo url to audit
...
Example:
...
  -v, --verbose        Show verbose output from gitleaks audit
...
```

Comment: yeah if it's a private repo, not sure how to get the ssh keys in there

Comment: It's not private. The command you included works for me. IIUC the repo that's used is just an example. You'd replace `github.com/zricethezav...` with whatever repo you would like to audit.